# AjaxError when the GET request return 200 and valid JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html-framework-7

I'm doing some simple Ajax GET call like this:

```
{
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    success: func,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
}
```

The call succeeds and returns 200 and a valid json string. But `ajaxError` keeps getting fired.

If I remove `dataType: 'json'` part, it's fine and I can manually parse the json string without any problem.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the returned object for inspection - I couldn't find a problem.

[image]
[image]

Note: I'm using Framework7's implementation of jQuery but I hardly believe that they have a bug.

Comment: _But ajaxError keeps getting fired_ And what does it say?

Comment: @Andreas It doesn't say things. I have an `ajaxError` callback registered. Anyways, I attached one more picture to show the `ajaxError` event.

Comment: If the error event is triggered then there is an [error message](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/#ajaxError-handler)...

Comment: Yes but the request went OK and the json text is valid. What was the error?

Comment: Does the server provide the correct header for json ?